# Exercise 2.7.3 of Prof. Weibel H-Book is wrong. Suggestion for an errata.

Tags: homological-algebra

In this exercise, we have to prove that there is an isomorphism $$\text{Hom}(\text{Tot}^{\oplus}(P\otimes Q),I)\cong \text{Hom}(P,\text{Tot}^{\prod}(\text{Hom}(Q,I))$$ of double complexes.

But if I choose $I$ to be the cochain complex with only $I_0$ (all the other abelian groups of other degree equals to zero) I get $$\text{Hom}(\text{Tot}^{\oplus}(P\otimes Q),I)_{p,q}=\prod_n\text{Hom}(P_{p-n},\text{Hom}(Q_n,I_q))$$ which is $0$ if $q\neq 0$ and $$\text{Hom}(P,\text{Tot}^{\prod}(\text{Hom}(Q,I))_{p,q}=\text{Hom}(P_p,\text{Hom}(Q_{q},I_0))=\text{Hom}(P_p\otimes Q_q,I_0)$$ and they clearly differs.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Your computation of $\text{Tot}^{\prod}(\text{Hom}(Q,I))_q$ is wrong.

Comment: @Hanno It should be $\prod_n \text{Hom}(Q_{q-n},I_n)$ right ?

Comment: @Hanno If my previous comment is right, I do not see any difference ...

Comment: You are right and I am wrong. I am sorry!

Comment: @Hanno Thank you for your comment. If you still have some time for this question can you look at my answer and give your precious opinion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the only way I can make this exercise works is by symmetrizing further the two expressions by looking at the $\text{Tot}^{\prod}$ of each terms of the equality.

So we get $$\text{Tot}^{\prod}(\text{Hom}(\text{Tot}^{\oplus}(P\otimes Q),I))\cong \text{Tot}^{\prod}(\text{Hom}(P,\text{Tot}^{\prod}(\text{Hom}(Q,I)))$$

which should be added in the Errata for the H-Book of Prof. Weibel to save us a lot of time !

Comment: Maybe I am confusing things again, but I think this is right and can - by definition of the Hom-complex as the product-totalization of the Hom-bicomplex - be restated as an isomorphism between Hom-complexes.

Comment: @Hanno I think you are right, but in this exercise Prof. Weibel specifically ask to show an isomorphism between the **double** complex Homs and not the simple complex product-totalization of the Homs bicomplex. Hence my confusion

Comment: Yes. My comment was meant to confirm your observations and to only add the note that the isomorphism you state simplifies in terms of hom-complexes.

Comment: And in Rotman's *"An Introduction to Homological Algebra"*, Exercise 10.9 (after Section 10.4) is indeed the "$\mathrm{Tot}^{\prod}$ version" instead of Weibel's "double complex version".

Comment: ... And there Rotman used this property accompanied by the following Exercise 10.10 there to give a non-spectral-sequence proof of the Kunneth formula in Theorem 10.81.